# Scaffold image pack for iOS

Tags: ios, icons

I've been wasting almost an hour looking for something like a default image pack for iOS dev, including all icon sizes and launch images. Does anyone know of a generator of sorts that can bundle all sizes in a package? Maybe based on a small icon you can upload? Or just something basic.

I wanted to avoid wasting time by assembling each image one by one with its specific size and whatnot, but it seems it would have been the easier route. These would be just scaffold images until final designs are available.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question, but if you're looking for help with all the various sizes of icons for an app, go here -> http://appicontemplate.com